# Deciding which controller@action to be called based on a given parameters

Tags: laravel

I have to build an api. 
It has one route. The client is sending a POST request with an XML.
Based on that xml, I have to decide witch controller@action to be called.
And I have a lot of controllers.

Unfortunately I can't modify the client side.

Do you have any suggestion how can i do that in a Laravel way?

For example

```
POST["body"] =
"...
<controller>content</controller>
<action>index</action>
..."
```

I want to call a ContentController::index()

Thx!

Comment: I can't provide you the answer, but you should take a look at php's reflection. http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.invoke.php

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you got as far as parsing the XML? Try something and post back with your code.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't accurate. But I didn't know how to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for the reflection stuff. It is a big magic, worth the effort to look into it deeper.

I have no problem to parse the xml. So here is a simplier example

URL: `/api/request/content/show`

Routes.php

```
Route::get('api/request/{controller}/{action}', 'ApiController@request');
```

ApiController.php

```
class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function request($controller, $action)
    {
        //some error check

        $controller = 'App\Http\Controllers\\' . ucfirst($controller) . 'Controller';
        $params = "Put some params here";

        $reflectionMethod = new \ReflectionMethod($controller, $action);
        $reflectionMethod->invoke(new $controller, $params);

    }
}
```

ContentController.php

```
class ContentController extends Controller
{
    public function show($params)
    {
        dd($params);
    }
}
```

And it is working!

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A better option is to use `App::call();` invoking controller with ReflectionMethod might not let you use response() inside your new forwarded controller and other laravel goodies.

Here is my try on this: `/api/request/content/show`

**Routes web.php or api.php**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ApiController;

Route::get('api/request/{controller}/{action}', [ApiController::class, 'request']);
```

**ApiController.php**

```
class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function request($controller, $action)
    {
        //some error check
        
        return App::call('App\Http\Controllers\\'.ucfirst($controller).'Controller@'.$action);

    }
}
```

**ContentController.php**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ContentController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request);
    }
}
```

This will allow you more freedom.